Variable is not passed to rsync in my bash script
I have a simple bash script which copies files using rsync:
#! /bin/bash

read -p "enter src: " sdir
read -p "enter target: " tdir
read -p "enter name of log file: " lfile

current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

rsync_options="-avb --exclude Documents --exclude Desktop --exclude Music --exclude Downloads --exclude Videos --exclude Backgrounds --exclude Pictures --exclude .cache --exclude .cabal --backup-dir $tdir/current_date --delete"

$(which rsync) $rsync_options $sdir $tdir/$current_date.$lfile >> /home/paul/Documents/logs/backup_$current_date.$lfile

When I run this, I get
paul on arch ~ took 8s
10:07 ❯ backup1.sh
enter src: ~/
enter target: /run/media/paul/7b266343-ee12-4e6b-bff5-77307f299ba0/Vostro/
enter name of log file: home
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/home/paul/~" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.3.0]

However, when I delete $sdir and write in the actual directory ~/, the script runs as expected. Why is the variable $sdir not passed, but the others are?
I tried running the script from several directories, although I do not see that this would make a difference. I rewrote this script in a different way:
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]
then 
    echo "Usage: backup.sh <source_directory> >target_directory>"
    echo "Please try again."
    exit 1
fi   

if ! command -v rsync > /dev/null 2>&1
then echo "This script requires rsync"
    exit 2
fi

current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

rsync_options="-avb --exclude Documents --exclude Desktop --exclude Music --exclude Downloads --exclude Videos --exclude Backgrounds --exclude Pictures --exclude .cache --exclude .cabal --backup-dir $2/current_date --delete"

$(which rsync) $rsync_options $1 $2/$current_date.$3 >> /home/paul/Documents/logs/backup_$current_date.$3.log

# run this script doing something like: backup.sh /home/paul /run/media/paul/7b266343-ee12-4e6b-bff5-77307f299ba0 paul

and this worked as expected

Stop using ~.  My guess is that it is being passed in, and you are seeing it in the error message where it state "/home/paul/~".  The problem is, the way you are passing it in, the shell never gets a chance to expand ~ to /home/paul, so rsync is looking for the literal name ~.

Makes sense. I will try it and report back. Thanks!

Not strictly relevant to the question, but I'd recommend using an array for the rsync_options: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- Also Why not use "which"? What to use then?

~ only gets expanded to the home directory path under certain specific circumstances, none of which apply here. Therefore, it's just being treated as a normal filename rather than a shortcut for the home directory.

Shouldn't $target be $tdir?

When you write a literal ~ at the start of a word, tilde expansion occurs. For instance, ~paul is expanded to the home directory of paul. However, tilde expansion is done before parameter expansion. You would have to use eval (with all its perils) to force tilde expansion for a variable holding the tilde word. One alterntative would be to write your script in zsh instead of bash, as zsh allows you to explicitly request tilde expansion for a variable.

@Barmar yes, right, It is a typo. Thanks.

@user1934428 I did not know about the order of expansion. Thanks.

Make sure you memorize this. Otherwise it is difficult to do any bash programming.

@Matematleta Don't you think you should fix the typo now that you know about it?

@Barmar Right, done. Thanks.
